# How to trigger or invoke the onResize event in Delphi on TMS WEB Core?

Tags: delphi, tms, onresize, tms-web-core

I have a UI with a `TWebLabel` that is right-aligned. The `Caption` is dynamically set for the label.

When the page is loaded and the `Caption` is set, then the label doesn't fit in:

[image: Header]

But as soon as I resize the page, then it fixes itself:

[image: Header]

---

So it's almost as if it doesn't know that the `Caption` changed and doesn't know that it needs to increase the label's width. It only realizes once I resize the page and then it fixes the UI for the new dynamic content.

So how can I trigger or invoke the `onResize` of the `TWebForm` so that the page thinks that it resized?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to invoke it using JavaScript through the `ASM` code block:

```
asm
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
end;
```

Using the above code will trigger the form's `onResize` event and will fix the Label's issue also.

Comment: You must not put much value on your time. A lot of the questions you've been asking about TMS WEB Core can be searched on their support site. I have their ALL-ACCESS pass so I don't know if it's available or not to people with the free demo code. But when I send a ticket to support, I usually get an answer in a day or two, and frequently it's Bruno saying it will be fixed/added to the next release. They do update stuff very regularly. Your post about tab positions on Page Controls is something I'm sure they'd add, saving you a bunch of time. But since you don't value your time very much...